# Why does indexing in an array break type safety in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, indexing, types

The whole point of adding static types to JavaScript is to provide some guarantees about type safety. I noticed that array indexing seems to break type safety without using any dirty tricks like `as any` or the not null assertion operator.

```
let a: Array<number> = [1,2,3,4];
let b: number = a[4]; //undefined
```

This code does not cause any TypeScript errors, even though it is plain to see that it will violate type safety. It seems to me that the type of an `Array<T>` acted upon by the index operator `[]` should be type `T | undefined`, however the TypeScript compiler treats it as if it was type `T`.

Upon further investigation, I discovered that this behavior applies to use of the index operator on objects as well. It would seem that the index operator is not type safe in any case.

```
class Example {
  property: string;
}

let c: Example = { property: "example string" }
let d: string = c["Not a property name"]; //undefined
```

Use of the index operator on an object with arbitrary key returns type `any`, which can be assigned to any type without causing type errors. However, this can be resolved by using the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option.

My question is why does something as basic as indexing on an array break type safety? Is this a design constraint, an oversight, or a deliberate part of TypeScript?

Comment: That's an open issue. Please follow the [discussion on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) and let them know if you have any further ideas on this.

Comment: It is an intentional work around because Javascript objects are not actually typed classes in the way Typescript likes to treat them.  I have had to use this method several time when I receive back an object that I know may have had additional properties added by another function.

Comment: I wrote a workaround: https://github.com/danielnixon/total-functions

Comment: Thankfully Array.at behaves as you might expect, returning `T | undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the *why* part of your question, it is because the developers of TypeScript thought that it would be too uncomfortable if you always had to check for `undefined` results when indexing an `Array`.

For example, the following code would not type-check:

```
var arr: number[]
var s = 0
for (var i in arr) {
  s += arr[i]
}
```

Furthermore, because JavaScript `Array`s can be sparse, even if the index is known to not be out of bounds (as in, `>= 0` and `< arr.length`), you can still get `undefined`, so there seems to be no way to fully infer actual unsafe indexing.

For more on this, see the issues [TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) and [TypeScript#11122](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11122).

Comment: That is a reasonable motive, so that developers can continue to use idiomatic JavaScript array indexing. Typescript has the idea of a "sliding scale" of type checking, so it would be nice to see a more strict array index as an option that could be turned on. However, as [issue #11122](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11122) points out, few languages offer full type safety with array indexing.

Answer (score 3):

> Use of the index operator on an object with arbitrary key returns type any, which can be assigned to any type without causing type errors. However, this can be resolved by using the --noImplicitAny compiler option.

Yes. Use the `noImplicitAny`, if you care for strict safety. Also `strict:true` (which `strictNullChecks` as well as others).

> My question is why does something as basic as indexing on an array break type safety? Is this a design constraint, an oversight, or a deliberate part of TypeScript?

There are levels of safety. `strict` is the strongest. You choose how strict you want to be with your code.

## More

From https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/options/intro.html

> That said, traditionally programming languages have a hard boundary between what is and isn't allowed by the type system. TypeScript is different in that it gives you control on where you put the slider.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question was specifically about indexing on type Array<T>, which returns type T.

Answer (score 3):

Since Typescript version 4.1 we have the setting [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess). Enabling this basically works like what you describe - the inferred type of index access always includes `undefined`. In your example, the type of `b` becomes `T | undefined`.